# Can't open GPARTED

Tags: gparted

When trying to use GPARTED, the first thing I do is try to install the app despite I get **gparted is already the newest version (1.0.0-0.1build1)**, later on, can not open the program.

I bet should be a bug.

[image]

Any help?

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Comment: [This may be the answer you're looking for](https://askubuntu.com/a/523477/1222991) 

Comment: SUPER > gparted

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open Gparted terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/386420/how-to-open-gparted-terminal)

Comment: gparted is a seerios tool that can destroy your hard drives in an instant. You must use sudo to run it from the terminal `sudo gparted` will get it launched.

Comment: The data on the drives I do not think the drives.

Comment: what gives `echo $PATH` Normally gparted lies in `/usr/sbin/gparted`  Try to start it with `pkexec gparted`

Comment: @matigo I've already installed using either apt-get or apt

Comment: @guiverc it talks abt parted in the console & ain't what am looking for.

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details; but if you're using a text only system, you cannot use GUI tools.  (we only know about your system from what you tell us, and you've provided almost no details)  ; it opens fine on my own system (in GUI) using detail from that answer - but my system may differ to your *unstated* system as I'm using a desktop release.  You may have changed your $PATH, but again you've not provided any OS & release details so I don't know what's default for your *unstated* system.

Comment: @guiverc do I need to specify my OS if this is a forum that its name is **AskUbuntu** ?!

Comment: Ubuntu has many products, you've provided no release details that provide clues as to your stack (I asked for OS & release details if you look).  Yes you used an `apt-get` in your paste, which tells me you're not on a *year* product Ubuntu system (eg. Ubuntu Core 20) as they are *snap* only and the command would be `snap install`... but the command would work if using a supported desktop release as I've already mentioned & tested on my own box.  Release details allow us to understand better your stack & the differences to the stack we use ourselves (ie. what we tend to assume)...

Comment: @guiverc you are right, haven't noticed release before, beg you pardon. Anyway, I used both apt and apt-get for installing GPARTED. Not present in the Snap's package